# How to tidy a .Net XmlDocument text before writing it to file?

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, xmldocument

Using XmlDocument Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(VS.85).aspx

How can I tidy the XML text so it is indented and placed on new lines correctly before calling  Save()?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Save() overload that takes an [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) and configure the XmlWriter using a [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) instance. For example

```
 XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
 settings.Indent = true;
 settings.IndentChars = "  ";
 settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

 //Using XmlWriter to create xml file.
 using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("some-file.xml",settings))
 {
  doc.Save(writer)
 }
```

Comment: thanks that looks like just what a i need but strangely it seems to be having no effect!?